# jquery ajax - multiple checkbox state problems

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with multiple checkboxes. I also have the following code to return the state of these checkboxes.

A) returns "undefined"
B) returns "on" no matter if it is checked or not.
C,D) if I check just C then it also sets D to "true".I only want C to be "true".

```
$('#button').click(
function() {

    var A = $('#id_a').attr('checked');
    var B = $('#id_b').val();
    var C = $('#id_c').is(':checked');
    var D = $('#id_d').is(':checked');

    $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "&A="+A+"&B="+B+"&C="+C+"&D="+D,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#display').html(data);   
            }
         });
}
```

);

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post your markup.

Comment: Use `.prop('checked')` .. That should get you the right state of the checked property

Comment: Yeah, check out the differences between `attr()` and `prop()` since jQuery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ vs. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's **`.prop()`** method will return a boolean value for `"checked"`.

This is the benefit of `.prop()` over `.attr()`, that `.prop()` returns the type of value that fits the input while `.attr()` returns what's stored via HTML.

`.prop()` was added to jQuery in 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/49XDM/1/

```
var A = $('#id_a').prop('checked');
var B = $('#id_b').prop('checked');
var C = $('#id_c').prop('checked');
var D = $('#id_d').prop('checked');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and check out the section "Attributes vs. Properties". It actually talks about the "checked" property.

Answer (score 0):

> if I check just C then it also sets D to "true".I only want C to be
>   "true".

`.is(':checked')` always returns a boolean, and if you're having issues with it, the problem is elsewhere.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var data = {};
    $.each(['a','b','c','d'], function(_,el) {
        data[el.toUpperCase()] = $('#id_'+el).is(':checked');
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : "test.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#display').html(result);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pdbja/)